# Grep string containing missing characters

Tags: unix, grep

Okay, so let's say i have the following string:

```
hello*********@hello.com
```

And I want to grep that string such that it finds any result that starts with hello, then has 9 characters that can only be letters or numbers, and then ends at @hello.com. How would I do this?

I know i can grep it using `.`'s to represent any character, such as:

```
hello.........@hello\.com
```

But doing it this way allows for other characters besides letters and numbers, and this screws it up. how would I filter this so it's just numbers and letters being searched?

EDIT: it would also be nice if it included underscores and periods in addition to letters and numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`grep '\<hello[[:alnum:]]\{9\}@hello\.com\>' filename`

To include periods and underscores, try

`grep '\<hello[[:alnum:]\._]\{9\}@hello\.com\>' filename`

Comment: How would I get it to also include periods and underscores ?